# has_many :through a has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to do the following in a Ruby on Rails project:

```
class FoodItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :food_categories
  has_many :places, :through => :food_categories
end

class FoodCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :food_items
  belongs_to :place
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :food_categories
  has_many :food_items, :through => :food_category
end
```

But calling the instance method `some_food_item.places` gives me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column 
food_categories.food_item_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...laces".id = "food_categories".place_id    WHERE (("food_cate...

: SELECT "places".* FROM "places"  INNER JOIN "food_categories" ON "places".id = "food_categories".place_id    WHERE (("food_categories".food_item_id = 1))
```

Which makes perfect sense - because of the HABTMs on FoodItem and FoodCategory I have the mapping table named `food_categories_food_items`.

What do I have to do to get `some_food_item.places` to look places up correctly through the mapping table instead of looking for a `food_item_id` in the `food_categories` table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first version of the answer was incorrect, but this one works perfectly.  I made a couple of typos the first time (the hazard of not actually creating an app to test) but this time I verified.  And a plugin is needed, but this is easy.  first, install the plugin:

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through.git
```

This installs Ian White's workaround, and it works seamlessly.  Now the models, copied directly from the test app I setup to get this working:

```
class FoodItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_category_items
  has_many :food_categories, :through => :food_category_items
  has_many :places, :through => :food_categories
end

class FoodCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_category_items
  has_many :food_items, :through => :food_category_items
  belongs_to :place
end

class FoodCategoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food_item
  belongs_to :food_category
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_categories
  has_many :food_category_items, :through => :food_categories
  has_many :food_items, :through => :food_category_items
end
```

Now "far" associations work just as well.  `place_instance.food_items` and `food_item.places` both work flawlessly, as well as the simpler associations involved.  Just for reference, here's my schema to show where all the foreign keys go:

```
create_table "food_categories", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "place_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "food_category_items", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "food_item_id"
  t.integer  "food_category_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "food_items", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "places", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:** This question has come up a few times recently. I wrote an article, [nesting your has_many :through relationships](http://kconrails.com/2010/01/28/nesting-has_many-through-relationships-in-ruby-on-rails/), to explain in detail.  It even has an accompanying example application on GitHub to download and play around with.

Comment: It certainly helps!
Thank you both for the solution and also for the heads up on HABTM. I'm sure this won't be the only place I'll apply this solution!

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago I wrote [an article about this](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/has-many-through-habtm.html). In short, `has_many` through a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association is not allowed by Rails. However, you can partly simulate the relationship by doing something like this:

```
class FoodItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :food_categories
  named_scope :in_place, lambda{ |place|
    {
      :joins      => :food_categories,
      :conditions => {:food_categories => {:id => place.food_category_ids}},
      :select     => "DISTINCT `food_items`.*" # kill duplicates
    }
  }
end

class FoodCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :food_items
  belongs_to :place
end

class Place
  has_many :food_categories
  def food_items
    FoodItem.in_place(self)
  end
end
```

This will give you the `some_food_item.places` method you seek.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Rasmus, your original setup now seems to work fine on a HABTM.

I'd suggest users try first before attempting a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

This is correct, because you can't peform "has many through" on a join table.  In essence, you're trying to extend the relationship one degree further than you really can.  HABTM (has_and_belongs_to_many) is not a very robust solution to most problems.

In your case, I'd recommend adding a model called FoodCategoryItem, and renaming your join table to match.  You'll also need to add back the primary key field.  Then setup your model associations like this:

```
class FoodItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_categories, :through => :food_category_items
  has_many :places, :through => :food_categories
end

class FoodCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_items, :through => :food_category_items
  belongs_to :place
end

class FoodCategoryItems < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food_item
  belongs_to :food_category
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :food_categories
  has_many :food_items, :through => :food_categories
end
```

Note, I also fixed a typo in "Place -> has_many :food_items".  This should take care of what you need, and give you the added bonus of being able to add functionality to your FoodCategoryItems "join" model in the future.

Comment: I can't get this to work - when calling some_food_item.places I get the same error. It's apparently a limitation in ActiveRecord (see http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/115029).

Comment: You're right, sorry.  I added an answer that fixes everything.