# Rails 3 complex SQL update alternative

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-update

I have an sql that i run on 2 tables:

```
affiliates_comisions.each do |aff|
  connection.update("
              UPDATE comissions AS coms,
              conversions AS conve 
              SET conve.active=0 
              WHERE coms.conversion_type_id=conve.conversion_type_id
              AND conve.user_id="+aff.id.to_s+"
              AND conve.active=1
              AND coms.method = 'one_time'")
end
```

My question is how could i make this in a better way if there is? I couldn't find a way to update a field that required a condition from another table to be true...

Let me know if you need other details.

---

### Update 1

The affiliates_comissions is:

```
total_pay_sql = "(SELECT SUM(payment)
                  FROM comissions AS coms,conversions AS conve
                  WHERE coms.conversion_type_id=conve.conversion_type_id
                  AND conve.user_id=usr.id
                  AND conve.active=1)"
affiliates_comisions = self.
                        select('*,'+total_pay_sql+' AS total_pay').
                        from("users AS usr").
                        where(total_pay_sql+">=5")
```

---

### Update 2

[image: Here is a diagram of the 3 tables that i use in this query]

And here are the models:

```
class Comission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversion_type
  attr_accessible :method, :payment

  validates_inclusion_of :method, :in => [:recurring, :one_time]
...

class Conversion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :conversion_type_id, :restaurant_id, :user_id, :active

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :conversion_type
...

class ConversionType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :conversions
end
```

---

### Update 3

After the suggestion made by @RGB i've made some changes and i added:

```
#To conversion model#
has_many :comissions, :through => :conversion_type
#To comission model#
has_many :conversions, :through => :conversion_type
#To conversion_type model#
has_many :conversions
has_many :comissions
```

And now i managed to get a select to work even tough this thing runs 2 queries and i'm not sure how this is better than me writing one query to do the update but maybe you can help me. So this is the select i managed to write to get the conversions that i need.

```
@conversions = Comission.find_by_method('one_time').conversions.find_all_by_active_and_user_id(1,affiliates_comisions.collect(&:id))
```

Now the problem is i can't run an update on this or how could i make the update query without running this select? ...

---

### Answer

I finally managed to get the thing working as i wanted to. Here is what i have after a few changes:

```
total_pay_sql = "(SELECT SUM(payment)
                  FROM comissions AS coms,conversions AS conve
                  WHERE coms.conversion_type_id=conve.conversion_type_id
                  AND conve.user_id=usr.id
                  AND conve.active=1)"
affiliates_comisions = self.
                        select('*,'+total_pay_sql+' AS total_pay').
                        from("users AS usr").
                        where(total_pay_sql+">=?",@@minimum_pay)

#we run a normal update here to set the one time conversions to active=0 so we only pay for them once
@conversions = Comission.where({:method=>'one_time'}).joins(:conversions).where("active=1 AND user_id IN(?)",affiliates_comisions.collect(&:id)).update_all(:active=>0)
```

This last line is the answer i wanted and combined with what @RGB said i've managed to make it work. This is the query that is executed by that last line:

```
UPDATE `comissions` INNER JOIN `conversion_types` ON `conversion_types`.`id` = `comissions`.`conversion_type_id` INNER JOIN `conversions` ON `conversions`.`conversion_type_id` = `conversion_types`.`id` SET `active` = 0 WHERE `comissions`.`method` = 'one_time' AND (active=1 AND user_id IN(41))
```

Perfect!!! :D I hope it helps someone else too!

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion this is not a very complex statement, and I dont think there is many more ways to do it.

Comment: yea, in rails you rarely need to write sql queries...are you using ActiveRecord models?

Comment: please specify your Models and Relations. In addition, what is the variable affiliates_comisions?

Comment: @RGB yeah i'm using ActiveRecord models...

Comment: do you have one for commissions and one for conversions? because if you do, and you have set up their relationships correctly, you can get this without a single string of SQL, as @davidrac said, we need to see them to answer your question

Comment: ..and, if you dont, you should since you have tables for them.

Comment: I've made another update let me know if it's all clear ;) Thanks!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre missing the relationship between Conversion and Commission through conversion type

add:

```
#add to Conversions
has_and_belongs_to_many :comissions, :through => :conversion_type

#add to Comissions
has_and_belongs_to_many :conversions, :through => :conversion_type
```

respectively to the classes

see for more help:
[has_many :through a has_and_belongs_to_many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150582/has-many-through-a-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

Comment: this way, from a `Conversion` method, you can go `self.commissions.where({})` and specify your user and active values...conversely, you could do something like `Conversion.find(1).commissions.where({})`

Comment: NOTE: you might need to use a different relationship than has_and_belongs_to_many, the key here is the `:through` option that allows you to make calls this way

Comment: I see ... Ok i'll try to play with these and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: its automagic goodness that keeps code really clean...SQL in Rails should be something you try and avoid as much as possible

Comment: I managed to get a select using what you suggested so i can get the comissions that have the required attributes but i can't manage to get the update to work maybe you can help me that's what i actually need... I'll add a new update. Thanks