# Rails: How to fetch records that are 2 'has_many' levels deep?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these models set up:

```
Course
  has_and_belongs_to_many Student

Student
  has_and_belongs_to_many Course
  has_many Books

Book
  belongs_to Student
```

How do I efficiently get all the Books for a Course with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Course.includes(:students => { :books })
```

Documentation is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), under "Eager loading of associations".

**Edited**

Sorry, I misread the question. I see your focus is on the books for a given course. In that case I would recommend something like this:

```
Book.includes(:student => :courses).where(["course.id = ?", @course.id]).limit(5)
```

It would probably be easier to add this as a method on the `Course` model:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  def books(max = 10)
    Book.includes(:student => :courses).where(["course.id = ?", self]).limit(max)
  end
end
```

That code might not be exactly correct, but it should give you the right idea.

Also, you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150582/has-many-through-a-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) question for a potential alternate solution to defining this stuff yourself.

Comment: Thanks Luke, Eager Loading helps. I have some special constraints on Books though, so I ended up with something like:

Course.where("courses.id = ?", 2).includes(:students, :books).where(["books.published > ?", 1.year.ago]).order("books.popularity DESC").first.books

And the biggest problem from this query is I can't add LIMIT to books. Is there a way for ActiveRecord to help me construct a query that looks something like the following?

SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."student_id" IN (21, 23, 19, 17, 18, 20, 5, 22, 4)

Comment: esjd I edited my answer to better address this, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you could use a through association and do something like...

```
Course
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  has_many :books, :through => :students

Student
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
  has_many :books

Book
  belongs_to :student
```

Now you can call Course.books which would return all books associated with a course.